# How can resume a backgroundtask instead of creating a new one?

Tags: c#, uwp, background-audio

I'm trying to implement a BackgroundAudioTask [using this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio), but when I close my app while the task is running, and reopen my app, it creates a new task instead of resuming the task that was already running. Because it creates a new one, it also plays 2 songs at once then. What is the best way to check if the task is running and resume the task then?

Comment: Do you mean you can reproduce the issue with the original example? Or after you made some changes? What the changes are?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with the original sample, without changing anything. Just open the app, play a song, immediatly close the app and open it again, then play another song. It'll play the 2 songs at the same time